# C++ Concept that requires a member function with an OutputIterator as parameter

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am playing with concepts and hit a roadblock. Or maybe it is just my mind that is blocked.

I want to create a class that buffers a "bulk-readable" data source. Such a datasource should have a member function that accepts an OutputIterator and has a signature like:

```cpp
template<typename It>
size_t read(It firstItem, size_t max)
```

My idea was to define a `BulkReadable` concept similar to:

```cpp
template<typename Source>
concept bool BulkReadable = 
    requires(Source s, Iter out, size_t max) {
        {s.read(out, max)} -> size_t;
    };
```

I am having trouble specifying `Iter`. I could add another typename to the template parameter list, but then the Buffer class that wants to use the concept would need to specify the type of that parameter.

The ideal way how I would like to use the concept is:

```cpp
template<BulkReadable Source>
class Buffer {
  public: 
    Source& input:
    Buffer(Source& input) : input(input){}
    ...
```

Is this approach even viable? If yes, how can I require a templated method signature if I do not want/can specify the type?

Comment: "*Such a datasource should have a member function that accepts an OutputIterator*" OutputIterators are things you write to. A function named "`read`" and "OutputIterator" don't work together. Also, C++20's ranges uses an iterator/sentinel paradigm to define a range; using iterator/size is non-standard and should be avoided.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer below! Please excuse the delayed response. The `read()` method should read from the source to the OutputIterator. I wanted something similar to `std::istream::read` but with a more general interface. But I agree that it is not quite a modern approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common problem of asking the wrong question of a concept, where you're trying to use them like you would a base class interface. With base classes, you're declaring the exact, specific functions that the derived classes are to implement. You want the user to implement exactly the function you say they must.

With concepts, you approach the issue from the other direction: what *usage* are you trying to create?

At some point in your code, you have some object, some iterator, and a size. And you're going to take that object, call a function by passing it the iterator and the size, and you expect a response back of a certain type. And this process has some meaning.

Then *that* is your concept. It's a concept that is based on at least 2 parameters: the type of the object and the iterator type. So that's what you should create.

If you have this `BulkReadable` constraint, then you must have some interface constrained on it. An interface that's going to call `read`. To call `read`, that interface must have an iterator.

So here are the options:

1. The interface is given an iterator type (directly or indirectly) by the user. If that's the case, then you just use that type in the function's `BulkReadable` constraint. If the iterator type is based on a complex set of operations on parameters, then you'll have to do some computations to compute the iterator type.
2. The iterator is statically determined. Then just use the known iterator type in the constraint.

The point being that, at the point where you're going to try to call `read`, you *know* what the iterator type is. And therefore, you can constrain things using that type. Your concept therefore is not really `BulkReadable`, but `BulkReadableFrom`.

In short, you shouldn't want to constrain a type on being able to take any type (or any type within some constraints). Check constraints against the actual types you're going to use them with, preferably at the point where they become relevant.

Comment: I tried approach (1) by adding the iterator type to `BulkReadable`, where I failed at was the specification of the iterator. I tried to use it like `s.read(make_move_iterator(vec.begin())` but was unable to specify the exact type of the iterator. Maybe I need to dive deeper into C++ iterator mechanisms.

For now, I use option (2) which works. Maybe I will revert to a "base class" solution when I finished specifying and constraining the application domain in which my libraries will be used. My intent with the `BulkReadable` concept was the removal of the explicit dependency to a base class.

Comment: I don't get it. This is a really common use-case. Can you  NOT do that with constraints!?? From the way you describe it, concepts are great at testing operator overloads, but practically useless for enforcing programming contracts. Times when I care with a type is incrementable: practically never, since type-punning is usually forbidden in the coding standards I'm used to. Times when I would REALLY like to give a short-circuit warning that a type does not provide required functions: umm. Daily? Maybe weekly.

Comment: @RobinDavies: You can constrain types to those which "provide required functions". The issue at play here is what "required functions" *mean*. It does not mean "function with this specific signature" or which "takes arguments that could be one of any number of types". It must be "function which takes these arguments". There are no "BulkReadable" types that provide bulk readability from *something*; there are types which are "BulkReadableFrom" some *specific* type. That's the question constraints answer. It's about properly specifying all of the constraint, not just parts of it.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: But what if you WANT a function with a specific signature??. Is there really no concise direct way to do that? Some way, in one line to indicate that the type must provide a function that matches "int foo(int value)", or "int foo(SomeNonTemplateClass* value)".  Not that difficult to hack; but each hack comes at the expense of readability for consumers of the concept.

Comment: @RobinDavies: That's not a thing you should *want* to do. Why should your template code *care* if the exactly takes `SomeNonTemplateClass*` or just some type that is implicitly convertible from `SomeNonTemplateClass*`? What matter is that your code has a `SomeNonTemplateClass*` and its going to pass that to the function. The details beyond that are irrelevant.