# Is there any problems with putting a lambda in a concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Take this concept for example - all classes that have a member named **func** should satisfy this concept.

```
template<class T>
concept has_func =
requires(T) {
   { [](T& t, auto&&... args){
         t.func(args...);
      }
   };
};

struct STemplateFunc {
    template<class T>
    void func(T){};
};

template<has_func E>
void FuncFunc(E a) {}

int main() {
   FuncFunc(STemplateFunc{});
}
```

Are there any problems with this trick - Putting a lambda in the concept or with putting generic lambda or variadic lambda?

gcc 10.2 accepts it: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/aPdavx)

Comment: Slightly related: [How can unspecified types be used in C++20 'requires' expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63443702/how-can-unspecified-types-be-used-in-c20-requires-expressions).

Comment: @dfri Thanks! That article - [Concepts can’t do quantifiers](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/08/10/concepts-cant-do-quantifiers/) is what ... inspired me (for lack of a better word) to think about stuffing a lambda in the concept in the first place.

Comment: But what would be the point of this?

Comment: Why would you need such a concept? I have a class with a member function named `func`. What can you do with it?

Comment: BTW what you are trying to do amounts to the existential quantifier, which is quite a bit less useful than the universal quantifier.

Comment: And another thing, the error that gcc emits upon FuncFunc(5) is of a wrong kind, i.e. not about a constraint violation.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It accepts the "universal quantifier" example from the blog above:

struct STemplateFunc {
    template<class T>
    void func(T){};
};

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/aPdavx) Maybe I'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: @DimitarMirchev Ok but... what is the point of this? Let's say for a given `T`, you know that `has_func<T>` holds - indeed there exists at least one type that you can write `t.func(x)` with. What would you do with that information? You don't know what `x` is.

Comment: @Barry Not sure about what's the point in all of this yet. Maybe none. Just wanted to get more opinions.

Comment: This is not "universal quantifier". A universally quantified predicate is a guarantee that something is true for all possible arguments. If your concept is satisfied, you cannot go ahead and assume that `t.func(x)` is valid for every possible `x`. Perhaps it happens to be the case, but your concept doesn't guarantee that. It only guarantees (or tries to) that `t.func(x)` is valid for some `x`. You cannot do anything useful with this guarantee.

Comment: Isn't that what member function templates are for? They can be instantiated with every T. So when I `static_assert(has_func<STemplateFunc>);` it tells me - yes, for every type  T there will be instantiated func(T t) because it is a function template.

Answer (score 2):

Going the route of using type traits seems more idiomatic and also works with all the big 3 compilers.

```
template<class T>
concept has_func = std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::func)>;
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KvhKfG)

Comment: Won't work with overloaded methods or templated ones though.

Answer (score 2):

The lambda in your suggestion is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if a `T` is substituted which does not have such a member `func`, because no valid instantiation exists of its function call operator template (and it can never be instantiated; [temp.res]/8.1).  This is the same restriction as with SFINAE.