# Concept for any noexcept invocable with any number of parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to use a Concept to constrain a template parameter to only allow invocables that are `noexcept`.
E.g.:

```
template<NoExceptFunc Fn>
void foo(Fn invocable) noexcept {
  invocable();
}
```

The difficulty I have is that the invocable should be any type of invocable (free function, lambda, ...) and allow any number of parameters.

EDIT: Thanks to [How can unspecified types be used in C++20 'requires' expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63443702/how-can-unspecified-types-be-used-in-c20-requires-expressions), I understand this is not possible to do in the general case, you need to know what `invocable` actually is, and then can constraint that.
Still, even when I know what `invocable` actually is, I do not know how to express the contrain, see below.

---

The following

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
concept NoExceptFunc = requires(T &&f, Args &&...args) { requires noexcept(f(args...)); };
```

works, but requires that the arguments types be explicitly given, e.g.:

```
template<NoExceptFunc<int, int> Fn>
void foo(Fn invocable) noexcept {
  invocable(0, 1);
}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to specify the parameters in the following case:

```
template <NoExceptFunc<??> Fn>
void foo(Fn f) noexcept {
    f(1);
    f("hello", "world");
}

int main() {
    auto lambda = [](auto&& a, auto&&... rest) {
        std::cout << a;
        if constexpr(sizeof...(rest) != 0) {
            std::cout << (rest << ...);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl; 
    };

    foo(lambda);
}
```

How can I say that the parameters can be <int> OR <const char*, const char*>?

Comment: This looks highly like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63443702/how-can-unspecified-types-be-used-in-c20-requires-expressions

Comment: @康桓瑋 Thank you, that question does answer "Can it be done in the general case?", with no. However, as far as I can tell, it does not answer how to write the "NoExceptFunc<??>" part for this specific example, which I am interested in. Should I reformulate my question to focus on that?

Comment: In general `f` can be arbitrary functor which has or don't have `noexcept` (or even a method) randomly depending on the arguments you call it with. `noexcept` can be conditional. So you _have to_ explicitly list all overloads you want to be `noexcept` at least somewhere, regardless of C++ version you're using. E.g. you can create your own concept `NoExceptOverloads<type_list<int>, type_list<string, string>>` which would check that a functor is callable with these specific overloads and is `noexcept`. Or you can just `requires requires`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using templated structs to deduce the parameters this works with non-generic/non-variadic callables:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_noexcept : std::false_type
{};
template <typename T>
struct is_noexcept<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::operator())>>
: std::conditional_t<is_noexcept<decltype(&T::operator())>::value, std::true_type, std::false_type>
{};
template <typename Ret, typename ...Args>
struct is_noexcept<Ret(*)(Args...) noexcept> : std::true_type
{};
template <typename Ret, typename C, typename ...Args>
struct is_noexcept<Ret(C::*)(Args...) noexcept> : std::true_type
{};
template <typename Ret, typename C, typename ...Args>
struct is_noexcept<Ret(C::*)(Args...) const noexcept> : std::true_type
{};

// turn into a concept
template <typename Fn>
concept NoExceptFunc = is_noexcept<Fn>::value;
```

Usage:

```
void func_noexcept(int) noexcept
{
  std::cout << "Function\n";
}

template<NoExceptFunc Fn>
void foo(Fn invocable) noexcept {
  invocable(1);
}

int main()
{
  foo(func_noexcept);
    
  foo([](int x) noexcept { std::cout << "Lambda\n"; });
}
```