# How to declare the signature of generic higher order functions with concepts in c++ 20?

Tags: c++, function, c++20, c++-concepts

The following code declares that the function returned by the function `Foo` must model a function that takes 1 int and returns an int.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <concepts>

std::convertible_to<std::function<int(int)>> auto Foo(){
    return [](int x){
        return 1;
    }; 
}

int main(){
    return Foo()(1);
}
```

If I now change the code and declare the returned function to be templated with auto like so

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <concepts>

std::convertible_to<std::function<int(auto)>> auto Foo(){
    return [](auto x){
        return 1;
    }; 
}

int main(){
    return Foo()(1);
}
```

I can't simply change the concept and insert *auto* as in `std::convertible_to<std::function<int(auto)>>`

Is there a workaround or special notation for this?

https://godbolt.org/z/sKf3Eb4MM

Comment: Concepts can only check specific types. It's unclear what `int(auto)` would do. What if the lambda has SFINAE for some types? I wouldn't involve `std::function` in this (which is essentially `std::any` for functions), but rather use `std::invocable` and other concepts/type traits.

Comment: What is the intention of the constraint in the first place? It doesn't actually affect the semantics of your template in any way. Do you want it just for documentation purposes?

Comment: Maybe dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63443702/how-can-unspecified-types-be-used-in-c20-requires-expressions

Comment: @user17732522 The problem with returning higher order functions is that you have to declare the return value as *auto* which gives no clue to the reader as to what shape is really being returned. You can write documentation and effectively say something like. ``this function returns a function with the signature int(auto)`` but I was hoping that concepts would allow me to formally do this and verify that what I write is indeed true. However after thinking about how concepts work I suspect this is just not possible.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing It is not possible. Determining whether a type is callable with any type as argument is not a decidable problem in C++.

Comment: It seems to be possible under *some* circumstances. https://godbolt.org/z/xzbx55bG7 One can create a type *Auto* that converts to any other type.  As long as the return value of the function under constraint is fixed it doesn't try to propagate the *Auto* type into the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work under some circumstances though certainly not everything.

```cpp
#include <concepts>

/// A type that converts to anything as a stand in for the
/// unknown type.
struct Auto
{
    template <typename T>
    operator T();

    template <typename T>
    operator T&();

    template <typename T>
    operator T&&();
};

template <typename Fn, typename R, typename ...Args>
concept callable = requires (Fn fn, Args ... args){
    {fn(args...)}->std::same_as<R>;

};

callable<int,Auto> auto Foo(){
    return [](auto x)->int{
        return (int)(x+1);
    }; 
}

int main(){
    return Foo()(1);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xzbx55bG7