# Concepts: Templated constraint

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, crtp, c++23

I'd like to represent this CRTP interface via a concept

```
template <typename Derived>
struct FooBase {
  void func1(std::integral auto i);
  void func2(std::floating_point auto f);
};
```

But I'm not sure how to represent the fact that `func1` can be called with anything satisfying a given concept. (In this case `std::integral`) Sure, you could enumerate certain cases like

```
template <typename T>
concept Fooable = requires(T t) {
  { t.func1(declval<int>()) } -> void;
  { t.func1(declval<long>()) } -> void;
  // ... etc etc
};
```

But this is obviously not ideal. (please forgive any subtle concept syntax issues.)

What I'd like to do is

```
template <typename T>
concept Fooable = requires(T t) {
  { t.func1(/* any integral type */) } -> void;
  { t.func2(/* any float type */) } -> void;
};
```

But I have no idea how to express that.

Comment: Looks like another duplicate variant of https://stackoverflow.com/q/63443702/11638718