# Writing a c++ concept for a type with static member function whose arguments start with a specific type

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have the following factory pattern in my code:

```cpp
class Base
{
    // New constructs the concrete type, but returns  a ptr to base
    // ... here represents actual parameters continuation (like int,  double) not variadic parameters
    static Ptr<Base> New(const dictionary& dict, ...);
    // Base is an abstract class
    virtual void update() = 0;
};
```

How do I write a concept which allows  **any** types (and number) of arguments after the first `dictionary` for `Base::New`?

My attempt resulted in:

```cpp
template<class T, class... Args>
concept DictionaryRTSModel = requires(dictionary d, Args... args) {
    { T::New(d, args...) };
};
```

which works, but requires passing the types to the concept (`DictionaryRTSModel<T, int, double>` will make sure `T::New(dictionary&, int, double)` is there.

Is there a way to skip looking at `T::New` arguments past the first one? I'm at early stages of development so significant refactoring is possible.

Comment: Are those actual c-style variadic arguments?

Comment: Yay, another duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63443702/how-can-unspecified-types-be-used-in-c20-requires-expressions.

Comment: no, those are not variadic arguments

Comment: Thanks for pointing the other question out, but I don't think this is a duplicate, as defining an `anything` type will still require me to pass the other arguments. Same as my attempt (Because Varargs not allowed in requires expression)

Comment: Concepts apparently do not support this kind of quantification ("anything") without passing things to the concept as arguments. At least I learned something; will probably continue with an inaccurate concept which doesn't account for this New method

Comment: Is `New` always a non-overloaded static member function? If so you could check the validity of `&T::New`, and destructure the result to check that the first argument is a `dictionary&`/`dictionary const&`

Comment: @ildjarn yes, it's an non-overloaded static member method. How do I check the first argument though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward given your commented additional requirement that `New` must never be overloaded. First, a trait to examine the properties of a function pointer is needed:

```
template<typename>
struct fn_ptr_traits;

template<typename R, typename ...Ps>
struct fn_ptr_traits<R(*)(Ps...)> {
    static constexpr bool is_noexcept = false;
    using result_type = R;
    using params_type = std::tuple<Ps...>;
};

template<typename R, typename ...Ps>
struct fn_ptr_traits<R(*)(Ps...) noexcept> : fn_ptr_traits<R(*)(Ps...)> {
    static constexpr bool is_noexcept = true;
};
```

<sup>(`std::tuple` is used out of laziness here; a trivial typelist type could be created instead to avoid the heavy `#include`.)</sup>

Then the concept:

```
template<typename T>
concept DictionaryRTSModel = requires {
    []<typename Traits, typename R = Traits::result_type, typename Ps = Traits::params_type>(Traits)
    requires std::same_as<R, Ptr<Base>>
          && (std::tuple_size_v<Ps> != 0)                                 // #1
          && std::same_as<std::tuple_element_t<0, Ps>, dictionary const&> // #2
    { }(fn_ptr_traits<decltype(&T::New)>{});                              // #3
};
```

1. can be changed to `> 1` if some parameters other than `dictionary` must always be present.
2. can be relaxed to allow a non-const `dictionary`, or something convertible to `dictionary`, etc. if necessary (requirements were ambiguous from your question).
3. is noteworthy as it's where most of the actual work is done in this concept – it's what causes the constraint to fail if `T::New` does not exist, names an overloaded function, or names an object or non-static member function.

Comment: Perfect! concepts are just cool! also I like the `same_as<R, Ptr<Base>>` detail a lot. I already had a typelist so I used that. Thanks!