# How to write a C++ concept that constraints an object's templated method?

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to write a concept that describes any objects that have a templated method called `reportsError`. The method has a template parameters `T` that is derived from `Error` class (defined somewhere in the source code), and can accept any number of arguments. The implementation of function `reportsError` internally will forward these data to `std::make_unique` to create a new error.

For example, the code below should compile:

```cpp
struct Error1 : public Error {}
struct Error2 : public Error {
    int a;
    Error2(int a): a(a) {};
}

template<class T> requires TheConceptIWant // don't know how to write this
void foo(T &t) {
    t.reportsError<Error1>();
    t.reportsError<Error2>(3);
}
```

but not:

```cpp
template<class T> requires TheConceptIWant // don't know how to write this
void foo(T &t) {
    t.reportsError<int>(0); // int is not a subclass of Error.
}
```

I have no idea how to write one, if you know, please write down your answer. Thanks very much!

---

*The OBJECT passing to the function `foo` doesn't need to be subclass of `Error`! It is the
**TEMPLATE PARAMETER ON THE METHOD** needs to be!*

Here is an exmaple object that I expect it can be passed into the function `foo`, (probably won't compile successfully in reality):

```cpp
struct ReportManager {
    template<class T, class... Args>
    void reportsError(Args&&... args) {
        auto error = std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

        // logic that handles and outputs this error to users.
    }
};

// somewhere

int main() {
    ReportManager obj;
    foo(obj);
}
```

Comment: The "derived from" part is easily done via `std::is_base_of<T,Error>::value;`

Comment: This question needs details and clarity. For example, show us some objects that have `reportsError` template method and also the driving code. Some more example how `foo` should be called.

Comment: The edit still doesn't clear things up.

Comment: I suspected this is just a variant duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63443702/how-can-unspecified-types-be-used-in-c20-requires-expressions since the argument can be *any* type that derives from `Error`.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is relatively easy if the constraint is put on `reportsError`, not on `foo`:

```cpp
template<std::derived_from<Error> E, typename... Args>
  requires std::constructible_from<E, Args...>
void reportsError(Args &&...args);
```

Now, if a user explicitly provides `E`, the constraint will only be satisfied for derived types of `Error`.

Defining a concept perfectly for "one level above" is not possible.
Concepts can only verify that certain expressions are well-formed, not high-level properties such as

> all specializations of this member function template are variadic and used to construct the given `E` parameter

The best you could write is:

```cpp
// synthesize a new class derived from Error
struct ErrorChild : Error {};

template <typename T>
concept ErrorReporter = requires (T &t) {
     t.template reportsError<ErrorChild>();
};
```

However, there is no way to verify that `reportsError` is variadic. You could at best brute-force it up to a certain emount.

```cpp
t.template reportsError<ErrorChild>();
t.template reportsError<ErrorChild>(1);
t.template reportsError<ErrorChild>(1, 2);
// ...
```

Then:

```cpp
template<ErrorReporter T>
void foo(T &t);
```

#### Further Notes

> ```cpp
> auto error = std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
> ```

Can be simplified to

```cpp
auto error = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```